# Timer for web API call in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a xamarin.forms app in which Iam using API call for displaying some data.The problem I am facing is the API call will become delay at some times.So what I am trying to implement is the API should check for response only for 20 seconds.If there is no response after 20 seconds, I will display some error box. So how can I implement this timer for APIcall? Any help appreciated.

Comment: And what if your API actually responds after 20 seconds what will you do then?

Comment: @G.hakim Bro if API respond within 20 sec, Then I will list some data , If it takes more than 20 sec, then i like to show time out popup

Comment: @G.hakim If result come after 20 sec I would like to ignore the result

Comment: how are you making this call?  If you are using httpclient you can just specify a timeout value

Comment: @Jason can you explain or provide some snippets?

Comment: Add a timeout as Jason mentioned,have a look at here:[httpclient.timeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout?view=netframework-4.8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you are using HttpClient

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

// exception if we don't get a response in 20s
client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0,0,20);

string responseBody = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
```

Comment: Let me check sir

Comment: Hi Jason , Will it same for HttpWebRequest?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout?view=netframework-4.8